# What is the LaTex code for this K and X?

Tags: characters

I've recently come across this symbols from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.2066.pdf).
[image]

Could you inform what are the code of this K and X? I tried `\mathcal K` and `\mathcal X` to no avail.

Comment: it's \mathcal but the exact shape will depend on the font (just as the shape of all the letters varies according to the font) If you have the PDF of the text you can show you can see a list of all fonts used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added the link to the paper. Could you have a look at it? I feel that the font is just as the one I usually use.

Comment: yes that's just computer modern/amsfonts ad euler fonts note its arxiv so you can download the tex source (although I just looked at the font list in the pdf)

Comment: try \mathcal with \usepackage{eucal}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As  [@DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) said: "try \mathcal with \usepackage{eucal}" and also here is the workable example for Your question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eucal}

\begin{document}
$V \subseteq \mathcal{K} . \times$\\
Let $(\mathcal{X}, \tau)$
\end{document}
```

[image]